# Cant insert image into CSS, I can only see a little blank square box

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to create a website. And I have a basic knowledge of HTML and CSS. I am using file base from hostinger and directly creating the code and at the same time updating the site so I see the progress. But I'm stuck and it says "expected `<bg-image>` but found linear-gradient" and RBRACE. Anyone knows how to proceed with this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS6dO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6LyJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

well you have done a typeError i.e you havend given "" in url("").

> use

```
url("filelocation")
```

it should works

Answer (score 0):

Please don't share your codes as a image.

`expected <bg-image> but found linear-gradient` the error says it all, it expects a background image, but it found linear-gradient.

Try this one:

```
background-image: url('images/kashmir9_cleanup.png');
```

Comment: Okej thanks for telling me, will try!

Comment: It worked fine for a minute, i could see the picture, but then it disappear, and now the only thing i can see is an empty squared box, do you know why?

Comment: my CSS code so far: *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
} 
.header{
    min-height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    background-image: url("pexels-cottonbro-9821881.png");

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

Comment: Empty square box means the URL of the image is invalid. You need to double check the location of the image file.